# Node error: Can't find module server.js

Tags: node.js

What does this error mean? Express.io is running

```
Elizabeths-MacBook-Pro:piazzahack name$ node server.js
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/name/piazzahack/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

server.js is open and in the correct folder. This ran as it is above at a hackathon two days ago.

Comment: What does "is open" mean?

Comment: Can you share the way you're including the `server`?

Comment: This means the 'server.js' is not placed inside '/Users/name/piazzahack/' this folder.Can you share the folder structure??

Comment: Can you share project directory structure and also server.js?